# How to use PHP inside JS files (with Symfony)?

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1, helper

I found this:
http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2008/12/13/use-routing-to-server-localized-and-dynamic-javascript/

But I saw that it has already been built into Symfony with the **use_dynamic_javascript()** AssetHelper.

I can't find any documentation for using this helper though. Any examples, links, or anything to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [this](http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2008/12/13/use-routing-to-server-localized-and-dynamic-javascript/) method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: [howto use use_dynamic_javascript helper](http://goodies.lemonsoftware.eu/php:dynamicjs)